# Using Call method with Constructor Function

Tags: javascript

I have a constructor function defined as follows:

```
function Person(fname, lname) {
  this.firstName = fname;
  this.lastName = lname;
  this.printName = function(fname, lname){
      console.log("Name: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
  }
}
```

Now, I can use the `new` keyword to create an object from my constructor function and call the "printName" method to print the created "Person" object firstName and lastName:

```
const p = new Person("John", "Doe");
p.printName(); // output: 'Name: John Doe'
```

I can also use the built-in javascript `.call` method with my constructor function to create a new object as follows:

```
Person.call({}, "John", "Doe");
```

Here's my question:
How can I call the "printName" method in this case?

Comment: `Person.call` doesn't create a new object. The object literal `{}` does. And it's only a plain object, not a `Person` instance, which is the reason why you should use `new` instead.

Comment: `Person.call({}, "John", "Doe").printName()` ? I dont get the question ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're calling the method directly, you would need to return a value from it:

```
function Person(fname, lname) {
  this.firstName = fname;
  this.lastName = lname;
  this.printName = function(){
      console.log("Name: " + this.firstName + " " + this.lastName);
  }
  return this;
}
```

Then you can call the result, like:

```
Person.call({}, "John", "Doe").printName();
```